# Pandas: fill a column value with 1 if column name exists in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame with three columns, each column contains the name of a column of another data-frame or `None`, and I would like to fill each row of the second data-frame with `1/0` depending on whether its name exists in one of the three columns of the first data-frame. Here's an example depicting the desired results...

```
df-1 : col_1   col_2   col_3
       -----   -----   -----
        A      None     None
        A       B        C
        D       E        B

df-2 (Initially) :  A   B   C   D   E
                    -   -   -   -   -
                    0   0   0   0   0
                    0   0   0   0   0
                    0   0   0   0   0

df-2 (expected) :   A   B   C   D   E
                    -   -   -   -   -
                    1   0   0   0   0
                    1   1   1   0   0
                    0   1   0   1   1
```

Do note that the first dataframe contains `None` values as well and these are not desired in the final result.

Some Code I have written

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = np.arange(len(df_1)), columns = column_names)
for i in range(0, len(df_1)):
  a, b, c = df_1.loc[i, :]
  df_2.loc[i, a] = 1
  df_2.loc[i, b] = 1
  df_2.loc[i, c] = 1
```

This code is for loop based and is obviously quite slow, **something more pandas like is desired**. I am also, **not able to handled `None` values in this code**. After the execution of  the code above the result is something like...

```
A   B   C   D   E   None
-   -   -   -   -   ----
1   0   0   0   0    1
1   1   1   0   0    0
0   1   0   1   1    0
```

So the question really is, how to do this faster, and how to remove the column named `None`. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), remove column `None` if `None` are strings and last get `max` per columns names:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='').drop('None', axis=1).max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df1)
   A  D  B  E  C
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  0  1  1  1  0
```

If `None` are not strings pandas remove them by default:

```
print (df.applymap(type))
           col_1               col_2               col_3
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'NoneType'>  <class 'NoneType'>
1  <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='').max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df2)
   A  D  B  E  C
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  0  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works like a charm.

`None` was not a string in my case, so 
`df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='').max(level=0, axis=1)` did the trick.